# Shortcut key to show and hide embedded terminal on gedit

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, gedit, text-editor

I have been using gedit for writing codes and compiling and running using the embedded terminal provided along with it. I often need to show and hide the terminal. The only option I have is to close the terminal and then open a new by checking the 'Embedded Terminal' option in preferences.

Is there any short-cut key or way to configure a short-cut key, using which I can either hide/show or close/open the embedded terminal.

By the way, I am using Ubuntu 18.04LTS with Gnome 3.28.2.

Comment: CTRL + F9 may be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed.